# 'error()' function in C++ works when I use '#include <iostream>', but not '#include "std_lib_facilities.h"'

Tags: c++, exception, overloading, header-files, name-lookup

I am learning programming with C++ using the book "Programming Principles and Practices Using C++", and I have no prior programming experience whatsoever. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (C++11, C++14, C++17)

In chapter 5 of the book, the author introduces a function called 'error()', which simply throws a runtime_error() function. I copied the code in the book for an example, but the compiler says "more than one instance of the overloaded function error()". I was using the header file the author prepared for the purpose of learning using the book, [std_lib_facilities.h](https://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h). When I instead used "#include ", the exact same code ran as intended. Why?

It gives me this error:

```
more than one instance of overloaded function "error" matches the
argument list, 'error': ambiguous call to overload function
```

This is the code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h" //it works when I use #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void error(string s) {
throw runtime_error(s);
}

double some_function() {
double d; cin >> d;
if (!cin) error("couldn't read a double in 'some_function()'");
return 0;
}

int main() {
try {
    some_function();
}

catch (runtime_error& e) {
    cerr << "runtime error: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The function error(string) is already defined in the header. Therefore the compiler doesn't know which version should be used. Remove your lines 3-5.

Comment: I can verify that what @m2j suggested will work. Just remove your own definition of `error`.

Comment: At around chapter 10 Bjarne will sort this out, and you can stop using this "training wheels"-header. Just read on!

Comment: Re: "It gives me this error:" -- it almost certainly gave you more than just what's quoted in the question. Most compilers also tell you where they saw the conflicting names. Error messages are often dense and confusing, but they sometimes have important information that's hard to extract.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the using directive

```
using namespace std;
```

that introduces the standard function `error` in the global namespace for unqualified name-lookup and using unqualified names to call the function `error`. That results in umbiguous.

You should use a qualified name as for example

```
if (!cin) ::error("couldn't read a double in 'some_function()'");
          ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I don't think that its intensional to have the same function body and name defined in multiple namespaces and add the effort to sort out the right one.

Comment: @m2j In the book the function is written as a user-defined function.